# MSBuild - Add version number to referenced dll name

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, nuget, versioning

Is there any way to change a referenced DLL name during build or during downloading via NuGet Package Manager and force it to contain version number in file name?

When I reference a DLL in .NET project via NuGet, the DLL is downloaded to directory like 'packages\NUnit.3.9.0\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll'
While building, the DLL is moved to bin directory with the same name as in package, e.g. 'nunit.framework.dll'.
I have few projects that shares the sames DLLs, but in bit different versions.
I would like to keep them in the same directory, but there is a problem with mentioned DLLs - they are different versions but the same name.
It sounds bit confusing, but it is connected with Jenkins build process and Unit  Tests and specific to my project.

Greetings

Comment: You can reference dll's programmatically in your code so you should be able to add the version number to the filename as an extension like so ```MyLibrary.1-0-0-0.dll```.  Sound easy enough to have a code snipped or build script that can pull that info out of the filename and use it that way.  That said, I've never tried it... It just seems like it should work.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - Typically, each assembly may target a different version of an assembly, but they can be synced up with [assembly binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to load the same version. It is unusual to load different versions of the same assembly.

Comment: I want to load one assembly version to one .exe, but during Jenkins build many projects may be built to the same dir.